# Dealing with minor-mode lighter and mode disabling

Tags: minor-mode

Have made a very simple minor-mode.  But calling

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/bin/toro")
(require 'toro)
(toro-enable))
```

does not show `Tna` in the mode line.  I also need a way to disable the functionality  once I call `toro-disable`.  But have to add something to my `define-minor-mode` function.

```
;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode toro-minor-mode
  "Focused editing."
  :lighter " Tna"

  (when toro-minor-mode (toro-tools)) )

;;;###autoload
(defun toro-enable ()
  "Enable `toro-minor-mode'."
  (toro-minor-mode 1))

;;;###autoload
(defun toro-disable ()
  "Disable `toro-minor-mode'."
  (toro-minor-mode 0))

(provide 'toro)
```

Comment: By default `define-minor-mode` defines a local mode, i.e. it is enabled in a single buffer. If you use `define-global-minor-mode` it will be defined for all buffers (if that is what you want).

Comment: I tried it and although it errors out because I don't have the `toro-tools` function, nevertheless when I enable it I get the "Tna" lighter on the modeline.